# Warning unused variable and assert

Tags: c++

Here are the two lines relevant to the question:

```
float velNMOscale = (1.0f + (vel2nmo[0]))* (1.0f+  (   vel2nmo[0]))*vel2z[0];

assert( APPROX3( vel2xy[0], velNMOscale ) );
```

The warning message is:

```
ApplyStencilXYTTIOpt_x86.cpp:2049:15: warning: unused variable ‘velNMOscale’ [-Wunused-variable]
         float velNMOscale = (1.0f + (vel2nmo[0]))* (1.0f + (vel2nmo[0]))*vel2z[0];
```

The variable is actually used in the call to the function "assert()".

Why the warning?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-DNDEBUG` in the command line options (or `#define NDEBUG` somewhere)?  If so, the assert is a no-op and the variable isn't used.

Comment: @Jonathan. You are right. So the -DNDEBUG will ignore any "assert() " instruction?   Thanks!

Comment: That is correct. The question was asked before but I could not find before asking  it. Feel free to delete this post. Thanks.

Comment: Yes.  The `<cassert>` (or `<assert.h>`) header looks at the current value of the macro `NDEBUG` each time it is included.  If the macro is defined, then the assert statement is compiled to a no-op (the equivalent of `((void)0)`).  If the macro is not defined, then the assert is active and the variable will be tested.